# Can you access a public static object of another activity from within inner class?

Tags: java, android

Let's say in `ActivityA.java`, we have:

```
public static Car mCar = new Car();
```

and then in ActivityB.java, we have:

```
horn.setOnTouchListener( myOnTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

     switch (event.getAction()) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
              mCar.Honk();
              break;
       }
return true;
```

when it comes to "`ActivityA.mCar.Honk();`", will I get an annoying red underline telling me I cannot access this or that?

Comment: Why don't you pass that object from `A to B`? spaghetti codes are always difficult to test and debug

Comment: `will I get an annoying red underline telling me I cannot access this or that?` Why not try it first.

Comment: try to make mCar.Honk() public

Comment: By the way, static variable access across activities is typically a bad design pattern.

Comment: @SamuelRobert How exactly do you do that?

Comment: @cricket_007 got any better idea? Because try to include them inside one compiling unit is near impossible.

Comment: it works. what error line it is showing ?

Comment: If you need to share an instance between two activities, you would declare some external class to manage that. The Activity is not a controller for the model class. Look at the MVC or MVP architecture for more details